# Add images to subitems in a ListView control

Tags: .net, windows

I need to add multiple images to a list view item that is in each row of the list view and each column has different images ?

Regards,
Fran

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this solves the actual problem, but if you need exactly two icons and can have them in the same column, you can use both the StateImageList and either the Large or SmallImageLists to display two images in the column. Just set both ImageIndex and StateImageIndex in the ListViewItem, and you'll get both images with the State image appearing first. The 0th column in the collection will get the images, but you can change the order that they're shown in via the DisplayIndex (so, column[0] will have the image, but you can make it display as the 5th column by setting the DisplayIndex to 4 and reordering the others if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to ask which version of the control you're using? The more recent one allow such thing. All you need to do is to add the images to its associated ImageList and set the appropriated properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following the question exactly.

If you are asking how to associate two images to a single ListViewItem in one row of a ListView control I don't believe it is possible.  I believe the image for each item acts as a unique key for that entry.

If you are asking how to create two entries in a ListView control with different images that otherwise have the same values you could use something like the following:

```
ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
listViewControl.SmallImageList = imgList;
imgList.Images.Add("image_one_key", new Icon("filenameOfImageOne"));
imgList.Images.Add("image_two_key", new Icon("filenameOfImageTwo"));
ListViewItem itemOne = new ListViewItem(("Test Object",imgList.Images.IndexOfKey("image_one_key"));
ListViewItem itemTwo = new ListViewItem(("Test Object", imgList.Images.IndexOfKey("image_two_key"));
listViewControl.Items.Add(itemOne);
listViewControl.Items.Add(itemTwo);
```

Comment: Hi Brad,
Thanks for your reply but i need an image to be inserted in sub items of the listview not just the first column of the listview item whic is done as you specified .